# Detecting the type of CSS selector from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, css-selectors

I have some JSON that contains thousands of different CSS selectors, here's a sample of the variety...

```
"#mid_ad_title",
"#mid_mpu",
"#mid_roll_ad_holder",
".SidebarAdvert",
".SitesGoogleAdsModule",
".SkyAdContainer",
"a[href$=\"/vghd.shtml\"]",
"a[href*=\"/adrotate/adrotate-out.php?\"]",
"a[href^=\"http://ad-apac.doubleclick.net/\"]",
"#mn #center_col > div > h2.spon:first-child + ol:last-child",
"#resultspanel > #topads",
"#rhs_block > #mbEnd"
```

So as you can see, the JSON is made up of a variety of selectors - some are just a class, some are just an ID and some are a mixture.

I'd like to use the relevant JavaScript "get" method depending on the type of selector, so for selectors that are just IDs I'd use `document.getElementById()`, etc.

Does anyone know of any regular expressions or something that will tell me the type of selector when I loop through the JSON? I.e `"class", "id", "other"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), if available, or a selector library like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) otherwise?

Comment: jquery does this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js idk what line it is but you can search for `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {`

Comment: Can't you substr the first character and compare it? for example if it was `.` it's a class and if it was `#` it is a id and so on ...

Comment: @Siamak.A.M what if it's `#foo .bar`?

Comment: @roryf Check out the answer blow. something like that i mean. You are substring the first char from the string.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M you missed my point, what if there are two selectors? `getElementById("foo .bar")` will obviously not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find more use in a `switch`:

```
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++){
    var s = selectors[i];
    if( s.indexOf(' ') !== -1){
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' '));
    }
    switch(selectors[i][0]){
        case '#': // ID
        results.push(document.getElementById(s.substr(1)));
        break;
    case '.': // Class
        results.push(document.getElementsByClassName(s.substr(1)));
        break;
    default: // Tag
        results.push(document.getElementsByTagName(s));
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**However**, the only reliable solution would be to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

Comment: The switch statement will only work for a limited subset of selectors - a single id, class or tag name. Combinations of those, attribute selectors, descendant or adjacent selectors will require `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @roryf: Edited so it will at least get the top element with the `switch`

Comment: if it's that limiting, it would better off throwing an error when it can't handle the selector IMO.